# Basis for Prime Sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a scheme with $\mathcal{A}$ a quasi-coherent sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebras. We say a sub-sheaf $P\subset \mathcal{A}$ is *prime* iff $P(U)$ is prime, or unit, for each open set $U$ in $X$. Define 
$$ \text{spec } \mathcal{A} = \{ P \subset \mathcal{A} ~ | ~ P \text{ is prime } \}$$
For an open set $U$ in $X$, and $s\in \mathcal{A}(U)$, we denote 
$$ B_{U,s} = \{ P \in \text{spec }\mathcal{A} ~ | ~ s\not \in P(U) \} $$
I am trying to show that $B_{U,s}$ form a basis for a topology for $\text{spec } \mathcal{A}$.

What I need to do is show that if $P\in B_{U,s} \cap B_{V,t}$ we can find a $W$ and a $u$ section over $W$, such that $P\in B_{W,u} \subseteq B_{U,s}\cap B_{V,t}$. At first I thought this was a straightforward exercise but some obstruction comes up.

One can confirm that, $B_{U,s} \cap B_{U,t} = B_{U,st}$ and $B_{V,s|_V} \subseteq B_{U,s}$ if $V\subseteq U$. From here it immediately follows that $B_{U,s}\cap B_{V,t} \supseteq B_{U\cap V,s|_{U\cap V}\cdot t_{U\cap V}}$. The problem is that it is not clear why $P$ has to belong to this smaller set.

Comment: You might want to look into relative spec.